# Remove reference with const references

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std

For a parametric class C, I want to get always the "primitive" type irrespective of pointer, const or reference modifiers.

```
template<typename __T>
class C
{
public:
    typedef std::some_magic_remove_all<__T>::type T;
}

int main()
{
    C<some_type>::type a;
}
```

For example, for `some_type` equal to:

- `int&`
- `int**`
- `int*&`
- `int const &&`
- `int const * const`
- and so on

I want `a` is always of type `int`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Look at how the standard library implements remove_reference, remove_pointer, etc (partial specialization) and simply do the same for all the things you want to strip, making sure it is recursive (remove_all_extents should be a recursion example).

Comment: @vonbrand Because I want to force C is always instantiated with a plain type, without modifiers, and my class use then a pointer to this "plain type". Other approach is to make use of conditions or static_assert, but perhaps removing all modifiers and adding textual preconditions is a more comfortable approach.

Comment: `int const & const` is invalid. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
template<class T> struct remove_all { typedef T type; };
template<class T> struct remove_all<T*> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T&&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T const> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T volatile> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T const volatile> : remove_all<T> {};
//template<class T> struct remove_all<T[]> : remove_all<T> {};
//template<class T, int n> struct remove_all<T[n]> : remove_all<T> {};
```

I originally also stripped extents (arrays), but Johannes noticed that this causes ambiguities for `const char[]`, and the question doesn't mention them. If we also want to strip arrays (see also ideas mentioned in the comments), the following doesn't complicate things too much:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class U, class T = typename std::remove_cv<U>::type>
struct remove_all { typedef T type; };
template<class U, class T> struct remove_all<U,T*> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class U, class T> struct remove_all<U,T&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class U, class T> struct remove_all<U,T&&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class U, class T> struct remove_all<U,T[]> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class U, class T, int n> struct remove_all<U,T[n]> : remove_all<T> {};
```

or with a helper class but a single template parameter:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T> struct remove_all_impl { typedef T type; };
template<class T> using remove_all =
  remove_all_impl<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>;
template<class T> struct remove_all_impl<T*> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all_impl<T&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all_impl<T&&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all_impl<T[]> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T, int n> struct remove_all_impl<T[n]> : remove_all<T> {};
```

It is normal if all the variants start looking about the same ;-)

Comment: Is it neccesary the line `T const volatile`? Recursion should also works fine here.

Comment: Try removing it... (yes, it is, otherwise it is ambiguous for a type that is both const and volatile)

Comment: @AndyT yes, I answered the question exactly as asked, but I agree with vonbrand that needing to do such a thing is suspicious.

Comment: Bad news. `char const[]` matches both `<T[]>` and `<T const>`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the warning, I had missed that issue. Writing all 11 combinations of const, volatile and [] or [n] looks painful. I could use mutually recursive templates where one strips const and a different one strips [] to avoid that, but again that's not so nice.

Comment: I could also make it `template <class T, bool=std::is_array<T>::value>` and specialize for `<T const, false>` to give priority to arrays over const, but that's still not very nice.

Comment: Make that `template<class T,class=typename std::integral_constant<bool,std::is_array<T>::value> >` and specialization on `<T const, false_type>` because of a painful limitation in the standard, and it works without increasing the number of lines. Other workarounds I can think of are mixes with the other answer.

Comment: the helper class wont work with `const char(*)[]` and not with `int const*`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Er, yes it does work on those 2 examples (note that the _impl specializations call the main remove_all, not the _impl version directly).

Comment: @marc ohh they do indeed. nvm :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use the standard library more, you can do:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T, class U=
  typename std::remove_cv<
  typename std::remove_pointer<
  typename std::remove_reference<
  typename std::remove_extent<
  T
  >::type
  >::type
  >::type
  >::type
  > struct remove_all : remove_all<U> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T, T> { typedef T type; };
```

which removes stuff until that doesn't change the type anymore. With a more recent standard, this can be shortened to

```
template<class T, class U=
  std::remove_cvref_t<
  std::remove_pointer_t<
  std::remove_extent_t<
  T >>>>
  struct remove_all : remove_all<U> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T, T> { typedef T type; };
template<class T> using remove_all_t = typename remove_all<T>::type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the `remove_cvref_t` function, it has been available since c++20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<int>, int> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<int&>, int> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<int&&>, int> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<const int&>, int> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<const int[2]>, int[2]> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<const int(&)[2]>, int[2]> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<int(int)>, int(int)> << '\n';
}
```